# How do I set or change the video refresh rate at boot time and at the linux terminal?

Tags: linux, boot, graphics-card, hdmi, text-mode

I am trying to increase performance of an old computer which can handle 1080p 60Hz just barely with OpenGL acceleration on.  Since not all video players (i.e. Web video) are equal to the local favorite, I am trying to decrease the load on the video chip and the graphical system by simply running at a lower Hz: 1080p 30Hz from the moment it boots.  I can change the settings in Gnome or KDE in Xorg and Wayland, but it seems it may require some mysterious code or compile-time options to achieve this effect at boot-time -- or are the linux boot video modes too restricted?

With a CRT monitor this is highly inadvisable, but this is an HDMI LCD setup with an APU Radeon GPU, so there is no concern about an irritating effect on the eyes or compatibility.

Comment: You should be able to change your video settings with `xrandr`. When you find the settings you want, add the command to one of the system start-up files.

Comment: AFH, Thank you for your comment. I have used xrandr before and find it much more fun to use than the X-related commands I was limited to in the old days. I'm not sure what you mean by settings. The most basic settings, "1920x1080@30Hz", I have of course, but it sounds like you're referring to something more. Also, I hope by start-up files you are referring to boot options. The most recent answer points to this and it seems ideal.

Comment: I was not aware of the boot option that [grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity) refers to, and this appears to be your answer. By start-up files I meant those in the various `/etc/*.d/` directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `video=` [boot option](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/modedb.txt):

```
video=1024x768@30
```

(The Linux documentation talks about old framebuffer-based drivers, but in all modern systems the option is handled by KMS/DRI drivers, in exactly the same way as mode-setting done by Xorg or the various Wayland compositors.)

You'll most likely still have to set it via GNOME anyway, though.

Comment: Upon digging into this in greater detail, I found that this is the best for initial video mode, but I was surprised to find that using a GL/graphical application like `mpv`, Xorg, or Wayland resets the mode to the kernel compiled default.  I have been investigating messing with the source of the kernel but there are no tools for grabbing and then modifying the appropriate KMS mode for my monitor/card.  It seems like I have to really learn the binary mode of the KMS mode files...